# How to get object's value in Pug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, object-serialization

I'm using Node.js to render a page using Pug. My JavaScript code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("index",{
    title:"首页",
    user:{name:"luo",age:19}
  });
});
```

My Pug code:

```
script.
    window.user = #{user}
```

But the result is like this:

```
<script>window.user = [object object]</script>
```

How to get the object's value correctly?

Answer (score 12):

Use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and change `#` to `!` to prevent the quotes from being escaped:

```
script.
    window.user = !{JSON.stringify(user)}
```

See [Pug documentation for interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html).